# Keymap doesn't work as is when you use some multiple modifier keys

Tags: key-bindings, osx

When I define and evaluate some complicated key combo like below and try to run it, I get an error.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "s-C-M-r") 'newline)
```

The error:

```
<C-M-s-268632082> is undefined
```

I can work around it by changing the key definition accordingly like below, but it makes my keymap really complicated. Is there a way to fix this?

```
(global-set-key (kbd "s-C-M-<268632082>") 'newline)
```

This doesn't happen for simple key combos like `s-r`.

My Emacs is OS X Desktop version 24.5 (9.0).

Comment: Works for me with the Gnome version on Ubuntu. Does it work with fewer modifiers? What is the value of `(kbd "s-C-M-r")`? Does it work if you use `[?\s-\C-\M-r]` instead? If not, what about `[(super control meta r)]`?

Comment: @Gilles How do you check the value?

Comment: Type it in the `*scratch*` buffer then press `C-j`. Or use `M-x eval-expression` or `M-x eval-region` anywhere then go to the `*Messages*` buffer to copy the value.

Comment: Interesting. I'm using a different version of OS X desktop emacs (from https://github.com/railwaycat/homebrew-emacsmacport) and don't run into this problem — `s-C-M-r` works for me. `(kbd "s-C-M-r")` returns `[142606354]`.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC the error you get is not when you execute the `global-set-key` but when you hit the <kbd>s-C-M-r</kbd> combination, right?

If so, the message indicates that Emacs doesn't think you pressed <kbd>s-C-M-r</kbd> but that you pressed <kbd>C-M-s-268632082</kbd> instead.  This looks like a bug in Emacs (AFAIK there is no character code 268632082).  It looks like some extra high-bit got set to 1 in the C code for an unknown reason.  Better `M-x report-emacs-bug`.